# Wordpress хлебные крошки

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

Помогите в вордпресе вывести хлебные крошки, просто чтоб был текст "назад" и возвращало на предыдущую страницу. есть готовые решения, только оно вывсвечивает рубрики или на главную сразу

Comment: Хлебный крошки - это "цепочка **навигации**". Соответственно  показывает навигацию по структуре документов сайта.  Не имеет никакого отношения к истории в браузере.

Comment: тогда чтоб возвращало назад в предыдущую рубрику или страницу, только текст чтоб был "назад"

Answer (score 0):

```php
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Можно просто записать в ссылку предыдущую страницу, и держать её в памяти пока она не будет отличатся очередной раз

Answer (score 0):

На предыдущую эту ту с которой зашли?
Или предыдущая это основная рубрика поста?

Если та с которой зашли по проще вот так сделать

```
<a class="back" onclick="javascript:history.back(); return false;">Назад</a>
```